# Multiple reputation values shown on Area 51

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51

On Area 51's main site, I have the reputation value of `201` and 6 badges

[image: Main]

On the discussion site of Area 51, I have the reputation value of `193` and 4 badges

[image: Discussion]

And finally, on Stack Overflow, I have the reputation value of `188` and 6 badges

[image: Stack Overflow]

I am pretty sure that reputation value changes don't work based off of a script that runs occasionally like tags do. And in the past, sites have always updated reputation right away. For example, the 15 reputation points I gained from this has already shown up on Stack Overflow's site. So what could be the reason for this?

Comment: <obligatory> Caching. Always caching. </obligatory> But seriously, I think we should wait a day and see if this fixes itself. You never know, even though it's not what I'd expect to see

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I know that it would probably fix itself if I gave it some time, I am just confused as to why it didn't update right away

Comment: If it fixes itself given a full day, then you have your answer.

Comment: it take some time to update ....

Comment: @CodyGuldner - Looks like it is just updated after I wrote the comment.

Comment: Have patience :)

Comment: Note: meta and main sites have different badges.